# josso2 idp initiated sso atricore_sp_alias=<REPLACE>

Tags: saml, josso

I am trying to setup browser based single signup with josso2.

In my idprovider under saml 2.0
it say:

idp initiated sso:

```
http://localhost:8081/IDBUS/FMKAPP/IDPROVIDER/SAML2/SSO/IDP_INITIATE?atricore_sp_alias=<REPLACE>
```

But that ?atricore_sp_alias= just seems wrong, but what should it be?

I tried to let my external service provider which need to identify the user, point to

```
http://localhost:8081/IDBUS/FMKAPP/IDPROVIDER/SAML2/SSO/IDP_INITIATE
```

but that gives me the following error: org.atricore.idbus.capabilities.sso.main.SSOException: Cannot find SP for AuthnRequest at

-------------- ADDED -------------

I found the solution. The problem is that the Josso gui don't show the url you need to use.

But the correct url is

```
http://localhost:8081/IDBUS/FMKAPP/IDPROVIDER/SAML2/SSO/POST
```

You can find all the urls in the xml file, if you save the project, and then export the identity provider.

Comment: i have some doubts while configuring josso2. can you help me. i have created a chat room

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and added it to the edit part.